# Upload video via cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to upload some video name test.avi to dailymotion..

I used cURL to login to dailymotion, and than I am trying to upload a video through this url http://www.dailymotion.com/widget/upload?skin=default

I scanned the requests when uploading some example video.. but it only gives me this:

Request URL

```
http://www.dailymotion.com/widget/upload?skin=default&upload_id=c73413240d828de0ce987018dddcb6ed&sid=5444350aa8f801e2605f8f6de15ac38c&urlbase=http://www.dailymotion.com&flash_mode=1
```

Query String Parameters

```
skin:default
upload_id:c73413240d828de0ce987018dddcb6ed
sid:5444350aa8f801e2605f8f6de15ac38c
urlbase:http://www.dailymotion.com
flash_mode:1
```

Request Payload

```
------------gL6Ef1gL6KM7gL6ei4Ef1Ij5ae0ei4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

test.avi
------------gL6Ef1gL6KM7gL6ei4Ef1Ij5ae0ei4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="test.avi"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------------gL6Ef1gL6KM7gL6ei4Ef1Ij5ae0ei4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

Submit Query
------------gL6Ef1gL6KM7gL6ei4Ef1Ij5ae0ei4--
```

However, I am not quite sure what to do with this Payload Request.. Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: assuming dailymotion accepts a standard file upload, you shouldn't have to do anything different in curl to upload a "video" than you do to upload a text file or an image, or any other type of file. a file upload is a file upload.

Answer (score 1):

That's a multi-part formpost, indeed possible to do with curl and its [-F command line option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F). Just provide one -F for each input field in the form.

Of course, you may also need to actually login etc with curl first, and then you may also need to track cookies etc. If that sounds complicated, you may want to start reading on the curl [HTTP scripting page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can only use cURL to transfer files via FTP. If you're trying to upload a video to a web server using their web interface or an API or similiar than cURL is not your tool.

Comment: Then, what should I use ??

Comment: Uh? Why wouldn't curl be able to do that? That's just not a very intelligent blanket statement...

Comment: I was under the impression that cURL could only download and upload files to and from web servers, not communicate with whole back end APIs. Perhaps I was mistaken.

Comment: @SevenBits not sure about the APIs you use, but every API I've worked with so far had cURL examples for their endpoints, I even test and try out most API endpoints with cURL, so in my experience cURL is perfectly fine for this use-case.